# UIWindow makeKeyWindow returns an EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, uiwindow

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] makeKeyWindow];
```

I've been trying to look up another way to do this exact same action but I haven't found anything. What happens is when this is fired, the debugger returns

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6f6d6582).
>   The process has been returned to the state before execution.

What ends up happening is my entire UI becomes frozen and accepts no touch events because the main window is no longer the key window. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Im using David Keegan's KGModal and its in the `cleanup:` that this is being fired.

Comment: is this iOS? If so it's makeKeyAndVisible if it's Mac code, i dont know

Comment: Yes its iOS :) UIApplication is iOS :) hehe

Comment: right... ^^ but i think you only have one window in iOS no?

Comment: You do, but you can create windows and do what you want with them. I've seem some other open source demos use windows to present viewControllers modally.

Comment: Well just in case you dont need a window to present a view modally. Would this bring a plus to a normal modal view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to write in my own animation to present something modally. After just a few hours of work I got everything working.

Answer (score 0):

To attempt and answer. Either the delegate or the window are unset at this point and the pointer is no longer referencing a valid object, and you cannot call them. Try logging the values of the delegate and then the window to see if they are both hooked up to objects.

Comment: Nothing would happen if either were `nil`.

Comment: I know the main window in the AppDelegate isn't nil. It is presenting the views and layouts